# XElement iteration failing?

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I'm trying to iterate over XElements so that they can be updated where a child element meets a condition. I've looked at answers from other posts and, as far as I can see, the method I'm using should work (but doesn't).

The first line of code selects the elements to update (this works as expected). If I put a breakpoint within the loop, hovering over 'existingContact' displays the correct contact element. However, the line 'Debug.WriteLine(existingName)' always outputs the value from the first element in the collection.

Any explanation as to why this is happening (and how to fix it) greatly appreciated!

```
IEnumerable<XElement> existingContacts = rootXElement.XPathSelectElements(namespacedXPath, _namespaceManager);

foreach (XElement existingContact in existingContacts)
{
    string nameNodePath = getNamespacedXPath("/CI_ResponsibleParty/individualName");
    string existingName = existingContact.XPathSelectElement(nameNodePath, _namespaceManager).Value;
    Debug.WriteLine(existingName);
}
```

Comment: i guess "/CI_ResponsibleParty/individualName" is a descendant path so it need to be replaced with "./CI_ResponsibleParty/individualName"

Comment: I swear I had this issue with XmlDocument yesterday, can you switch from using XPath to using XElement.Descedants?

Comment: Why use XPath instead of Linq-To-XML?

Comment: @Jonesy - Cheers, that did the trick, I'd still like to know why one works and not the other -  I'll investigate when I have more time.

Comment: @Jodrell - Simply because I've used XPath before, I haven't used Linq-To-XML and I have two days to finish this. (The loop shown here is a simplified version of a far more complex loop in the real app - it's not just a case of getting the individualName.)